# Laravel - can't output breadcrumb for a parent category

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, breadcrumbs

Using: https://github.com/davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs

I can print breadcrumbs in a View without any problems:

```
Breadcrumbs::render('category', $category);
```

Then if i want to print parent category - i do in breadcrumbs.php:

```
Breadcrumbs::register('category', function($breadcrumbs, $category) {
    $breadcrumbs->parent('home');
    $breadcrumbs->push('»');

    foreach($category->parent as $parent) {
        $breadcrumbs->push($parent->title, '/category/' . $parent->slug);
    }

    $breadcrumbs->push($category->title, '/category/' . $category->slug);
});
```

I cannot print category parent, here's my category model:

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->hasOne('Category', 'id', 'parent_id');
}
```

However, it outputs an empty `<li></li>`

How can i print category parent in a breadcrumbs?

Comment: Dear @Heihachi,I have the same problem.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each category only has one parent, as defined by your `hasOne` relationship, you can replace these lines:

```
...
foreach($category->parent as $parent) {
    $breadcrumbs->push($parent->title, '/category/' . $parent->slug);
}
...
```

with this line:

```
...
$breadcrumbs->push($category->parent->title, '/category/' . $category->parent->slug);
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Foreach needed in case if i had hasMany relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could make a recursive function such as this:

```
Breadcrumbs::register('category', function($breadcrumbs, $category) {
    if ($category->parent)
        $breadcrumbs->parent('category', $category->parent);
    else
        $breadcrumbs->parent('blog');

    $breadcrumbs->push($category->title, route('category', $category->slug));
});
```